# Access a DOM element in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, html, dom, aurelia

How would you go about accessing a DOM element in Aurelia? This is a broad and general question, but I have a feeling there are one or two preferred ways to do this. I have two current cases in Aurelia now:

In the template I have a form. I want to access the form element in the view-model, on VM canDeactivate(), to interrupt a user navigating away from a half filled out form. So the scope in which I'm trying to access the element can be considered local.

In another view-model I want to hide navigation on VM activate(). Navigation resides in another view-model/template pair so the scope may be considered global.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As Rob suggested, use `ref`. For your example:

**view**

```
<form ref="myForm"></form>
```

**viewModel**

```
class ViewModel { 

    canDeactivate() {
        var form = this.myForm;
        // do stuffs
    }
}
```

For more information on the ref attribute, see here: http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#function-references

Comment: Thanks! That is something like what I expected, I know the Aurelia manual is quite rudimentary at this time, but this certainly should have been in it. 
So I take it that Aurelia does not add any selectors sugar. 

I ended up using 
`this.element.querySelector('#form-id')`
which is nice enough.

I also came across a stub for a ES6 DOM-library which may be of interest:
[link](http://www.ericponto.com/blog/2014/10/05/es6-dom-library/)

Comment: One thing I didn't expect was that the DOM for the whole aurelia-app (in my case the whole body) was passed. In a sense, it might have been logical for only the part spawning from the template being passed. Not that it matters much. This way I don't need to find another way to access the DOM outside of my ViewModel scope.

Comment: The link given is broken

Comment: Best Answer, because it does include an example and the link to the reference. As we saw in this thread of answers, links can break. :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Don't be lazy!

Comment: I should get the "underrated" badge.

Answer (score 11):

Use binding system's `ref` capability. See the docs http://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#referencing-elements

Comment: Thanks! Very direct! To be clear, if I were to bind a text input for its value and also access its DOM element I would do both value.bind and ref on the template element, is this correct? Like so:
`<input value.bind="my_text_val" ref="my_text_el"> `

Comment: As expected (and prefered) I could only access a referenced element in its own VM, not in some other VM. So in my second case where I toggle navigation visibility I still use the injected element. Or is there a better way?

Comment: can't you import the view model and reference `viewModel.my_text_el`?

Answer (score 7):

Another option; **if your view-model is exposed as a `@customElement`**, its DOM element can be injected in the constructor:

```
@customElement
@inject(Element)
export class MyCustomElement {
    constrctor(element) {
        logger.info(element) // ==> <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that with the last version in a nested list item and though the element is working well, there is no info passed to the constructor about the element, so I'm forced to use `ref`. I'm always using autoinject so my syntax is a bit different and the logic may differ on the framework side.

Answer (score 4):

Just as another point I came across when trying to use this for myself, the `ref` variable isn't available during construction, and this isn't clear in the documentation. You can begin to reference the element as mentioned above (http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-basics/5) anytime during or after the `attached` method is called.

Comment: See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988599/when-does-binding-to-ref-attribute-become-valid-in-aurelia/29988982#29988982

Answer (score 0):

**Typescript** version

```
@transient()
@autoinject
export class ViewModel { 
    myForm: any;
    canDeactivate() {
        var form = this.myForm;
        // do stuffs
    }
}
```