# When does binding to ref attribute become valid in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

This is a follow up to this question: [Access a DOM element in Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863044/access-a-dom-element-in-aurelia)

Is there a hook in the Screen Activation Lifecycle which allows me to run code *after* `ref` bindings have been set up?  Currently it seems like there is a period of time after the `activate` hook is called when the `ref` bindings are not set up yet and then at some point they get activated.  I tested this by adding a `<div ref="myDiv"></div>` to near the bottom of `welcome.html` in a cloned version of the latest (v0.13.0) skeleton-navigation repo and testing the existence of the reference in the view-model like this:

```
export class Welcome{
  heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';
  firstName = 'John';
  lastName = 'Doe';

  testMyDiv() {
    console.log("Getting my div")
    console.log(this.myDiv)
  }

  get fullName(){
    this.testMyDiv()
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  welcome(){
    alert(`Welcome, ${this.fullName}!`);
  }
}
```

A snippet of the bottom of the template...

```
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div ref="myDiv"></div>
  </section>
</template>
```

This is a snapshot of what I see in the console...

```
welcome.js:10 Getting my div
welcome.js:11 undefined
welcome.js:10 Getting my div
welcome.js:11 undefined
welcome.js:10 Getting my div
welcome.js:11 <div ref=​"myDiv" class=​"au-target">​</div>​
welcome.js:10 Getting my div
welcome.js:11 <div ref=​"myDiv" class=​"au-target">​</div>​
(continues)
```

The print outs like this goes on indefinitely.  You can see that `fullName()` is being called regularly to update the screen if the name changes (I assume this is the dirty checking)... but you can see that at the beginning there is a period when the referenced `div` is NOT valid as a property of the view-model, and then it IS valid.  Can someone explain this?  Is there a way to hook into the view-model after the `ref` becomes valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, bindings are processed and available after the `bind` callback. However, in this case since you need to access the DOM element, you will need the ViewModel to be bound **and** attached to the view, so use the `attached` callback.

```
class ViewModel { 

    bind() {
        this.refItem == undefined; // true
    }

    attached() {
        this.refItem == undefined; // false
    }
}
```

As you noted in the comments, more information on the activator callbacks is available here: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#extending-html

Comment: Not correct, BUT, very helpful!  It pointed me in the right direction.  I needed to use the `attached` callback, both of which are referenced in the [docs](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#extending-html) under "Extending HTML".  Gracias.

Comment: I'm fixing it now, please review

Comment: `attached` doesn't seem to work to reference an element inside a `repeat.for` where each element is `ref="`currentElementInLoop.htmlElement"` unless I'm doing something wrong? If I `setTimeout` inside `attached` it works however.

Comment: @powerbuoy Look into the TaskQueue, which is part of the aurelia-framework.